# Error:Cannot read packageName from AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, package

When trying to open a project, first it asks me to install build tools 22.0.1 because project was built using those. I downloaded and Now it giving me this error.

Error:Cannot read packageName from D:\FAHEEM\MaterialDesign\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

[image: This is error screenshot.]

Comment: Nobody knows the answer?